# Render objects in a List in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to retrieve a list of Companies on a page. I consoled the incoming data just to be sure and it looks as follows

```
  "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "56407787-472f-44c9-b726-189798c7e217",
            "address": {
                "street": "test street",
                "postcode": "test 12",
                "city": "test city",
                "country": "test country"
            },
            "contact_name": "Angy",
            "contact_phone": "33333333",
            "contact_email": "angy@test.fr",
        }
```

The following component creates a list

```
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        maxWidth: 752,
    },
    demo: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
    title: {
        margin: theme.spacing(4, 0, 2),
    },
}));

function generate(props) {
    return props.data.results.map((com) =>
        <ListItem key={com.id}>
            <ListItemText primary={com.name}/>
            <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="edit">
                <EditIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </ListItem>
    )}

const Company = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    // console.log('data is ', props.data.results)

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        company list
                    </Typography>
                    <div className={classes.demo}>
                        <List> {generate(props)} </List>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
);
};

export default Company;
```

The following component renders the list:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

import Company from "./Company";

class CompanyList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        companies: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    companies: res.data
                    });
                console.log(res.data)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Company data={this.state.companies}/>
        )
    }
}

export default CompanyList;
```

I receive an error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I am new to ReactJS, and presumably stuck with this error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you insert `console.log(props)` to generate to check the content of your `props` and report back?

Comment: I notice that the console is called twice. The first time it's an empty array, while there are values in the second call. By logging only `props` the result remains the same except that it has a nested dict over it (data)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial state has `companies` which is an empty array and your `res.data` is an object. Initially, there is no `results` in an empty array. Due to asynchronous call, you should check if `results` exists. This `(props.data.results||[])` might solve your problem. Basically it says if there is `results` use it else use an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the state to the child that needs to use the companies data (so from the CompanyList component to your Company function https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Either use state management (Redux for instance) to link your Company props to the CompanyList state, or create a Context and combine with the useContext hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

Like what you're seeing, it's initially an empty array on first render than a nested dict (aka object) in your second render, but you're handling like it'll just be a nested object.

I do not know what exactly you need (rendering an empty list, not rendering a list at all, passing an object/array, etc.). Here is simple fix you can do so `props.data` is always a defined nested object:

```
class CompanyList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        companies: { results: [] }
    }
// ...
```